# How to mock my service using Mockito framework

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, junit, mockito

Hello I have struglling write a mock test according to my following method below;

my code below;

```java
@Component
public class CodeConfigBuilder {

    @Value("${promoConfig.prefix.length}")
    private Integer prefixLength;

    public void validateRequestAndSetDefaults(PromoRequest promoRequest) {
        prefixAndPostFixControlAccordingToLength(promoRequest);
    }

    private void prefixAndPostFixControlAccordingToLength(PromoRequest promoRequest) {
        if (promoRequest.getPostfix() != null) {
            int lengthControl = prefixLength + promoRequest.getPostfix().length();
            if (lengthControl >= promoRequest.getLength()) {
                throw new BadRequestException(Constant.ClientConstants.THE_SUM_OF_PREFIX_AND_POSTFIX_CAN_NOT_BE_GREATER_THAN_LENGHT);
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

my yml configuration below;

```
 #=========  Promo  Config  ========== #
    
        promoConfig:
          prefix:
            length: 3
```

my service below;

```
public void validateRequest(PromoRequest promoRequest) {
      
        codeConfigBuilder.validateRequestAndSetDefaults(promoRequest);
    }
```

I have a created PropertySourceResolver class

```
@Component
@Getter
public class PropertySourceResolver {
private int prefixLength = 3;
```

and my test class below;

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class CodeConfigBuilderTest {

   @MockBean
    private PropertySourceResolver propertySourceResolver = new PropertySourceResolver();
    @InjectMocks
    private PromoRequest promoRequest = new PromoRequest();
    @InjectMocks
    private PromoService Service;

   @Before
    public void init() {

        promoRequest.setPrefix("ABC");
        promoRequest.setPostfix("ABCDABCD");
        promoRequest.setQuantity(10);
        promoRequest.setLength(12);
        promoRequest.setCharset("ABCDEF");
    }

    @Test
    public void prefixAndPostFixControl_accordingToLength_for_Succeed() {

        int lengthControl = promoRequest.getPrefix().length() + promoRequest.getPostfix().length();

        if (lengthControl >= promoRequest.getLength()) {
            Assert.assertTrue(false);
        }
    }
```

I like to change my code according to test scenarios like ; when ... then return any idea? thank you.

Comment: What is exactly the question? Something is not working as you expect it to?

Comment: I like to change my code like;   (when...).thenReturn()

Comment: `CodeConfigBuilder` is a simple service, why do you believe you need mockito to test it? Create a valid `PromoRequest` and pass it to `validateRequestAndSetDefaults`, it should not throw. Then create an invalid `PromoRequest`, `validateRequestAndSetDefaults` will throw. Use constructor injection to simplify the creation of `CodeConfigBuilder`

Comment: So you would like that prefixLength can be adapted on the fly in your test, is that correct?

Comment: @lesika would you mind to write how to do it  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this simpler and better organize your code, abstract away the complexity of injecting the configurations by creating the following class:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "promoConfig.prefix")
public class PromoPrefixConfiguration {
    private Integer length;

    public Integer getLength() {
        return length;
    }
}
```

Then, you should make this a dependency for `CodeConfigBuilder`:

```java
@Component
public class CodeConfigBuilder {

    private Integer prefixLength;

    public CodeConfigBuilder(PromoPrefixConfiguration promoPrefixConfiguration) {
        this.prefixLength = promoPrefixConfiguration.getLength();
    }

    public void validateRequestAndSetDefaults(PromoRequest promoRequest) {
        prefixAndPostFixControlAccordingToLength(promoRequest);
    }

    private void prefixAndPostFixControlAccordingToLength(PromoRequest promoRequest) {
        if (promoRequest.getPostfix() != null) {
            int lengthControl = prefixLength + promoRequest.getPostfix().length();
            if (lengthControl >= promoRequest.getLength()) {
                throw new BadRequestException(Constant.ClientConstants.THE_SUM_OF_PREFIX_AND_POSTFIX_CAN_NOT_BE_GREATER_THAN_LENGHT);
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Now, in order to test this class you have to do it with three tests:

1. Test that `PromoRequest` is valid because `postfix` is null;
2. Test that `PromoRequest` is valid because length is valid;
3. Test that `PromoRequest` is invalid because length is not valid;

They would be something like the following:

```java
class CodeConfigBuilderTest {

    private PromoPrefixConfiguration promoPrefixConfiguration = new PromoPrefixConfiguration(10);
    private CodeConfigBuilder codeConfigBuilder = new CodeConfigBuilder(promoPrefixConfiguration);

    @Test
    public void promoRequestIsValidGivenNullPostfix() {
        // Arrange
        PromoRequest promoRequest = new PromoRequest();
        promoRequest.setPostfix(null);

        // Act
        codeConfigBuilder.validateRequestAndSetDefaults(promoRequest);
    }

    @Test
    public void promoRequestIsValidGivenValidPrefixPlusPostfixLength() {
        // Arrange
        PromoRequest promoRequest = new PromoRequest();
        promoRequest.setPostfix("ABCD");
        promoRequest.setLength(15);

        // Act
        codeConfigBuilder.validateRequestAndSetDefaults(promoRequest);
    }

    @Test(expected = BadRequestException.class)
    public void promoRequestIsInvalidGivenInvalidPrefixPlusPostfixLength() {
        // Arrange
        PromoRequest promoRequest = new PromoRequest();
        promoRequest.setPostfix("ABCDEFGH");
        promoRequest.setLength(15);

        // Act
        codeConfigBuilder.validateRequestAndSetDefaults(promoRequest);
    }
}
```

If you are using JUnit 5, you could replace the last test with the following one to easily assert the exception message:

```java
@Test
public void promoRequestIsInvalidGivenInvalidPrefixPlusPostfixLength() {
    // Arrange
    PromoRequest promoRequest = new PromoRequest();
    promoRequest.setPrefix("ABCDEFG");
    promoRequest.setPostfix("HIJKLMN");

    // Act 
    Exception exception = assertThrows(BadRequestException.class, () -> {
        codeConfigBuilder.validateRequestAndSetDefaults(promoRequest);
    });

    // Assert
    String exceptionMessage = exception.getMessage();
    assertTrue(exceptionMessage.equals(Constant.ClientConstants.THE_SUM_OF_PREFIX_AND_POSTFIX_CAN_NOT_BE_GREATER_THAN_LENGHT));
}
```

P.S.: do you mean `suffix` instead of `postfix`?

Comment: than you Joao Dias this is great  I mean suffix and postfix togethar can not be greater than length

Comment: Did my answer help you or do you still have questions?

Comment: Jao Dias I am really grateful I am trying you solition, however I got second parameter on codeConfigBuilder whis is public CodeConfigBuilder(PromoRepository promoRepository, PromoCodeConfiguration promoCodeConfiguration) {
        this.promoRepository = promoRepository;
        this.prefixLength = promoCodeConfiguration.getLength();
    }   promoRepository how can ı abstract this repo from class

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't and in this case, you need to mock it in your tests and adjust them accordingly. It would be easier to help you if you create a new question add there all the details and share the link here ;)